# SSH connecxion in the same computer

Tags: python, ssh, controller

I am using this [script](https://github.com/ARCCN/ctltest/blob/master/benchmark_throughput.sh) to run a benchmarking test between network controllers, since i am new to all this I have few questions if you could possibly help me with them?

- my computer is a i5-3210m core with 8Gb of ram, can I use it to be both the server & client and run this kind of benchmarking in it?
- I tried to run the previous [script](https://github.com/ARCCN/ctltest/blob/master/benchmark_throughput.sh) `./benchmarking_throughput.sh`, but it is still stuck in this phase:

  ```
  1
  NOX controller
  01_NOX
  GPid is , id is 0
  root@127.0.0.1's password: 
  Permission denied, please try again.
  root@127.0.0.1's password: 
  Permission denied, please try again.
  root@127.0.0.1's password:
  ```

I understood that I should configure my `ssh` or something like this, and after googling I modified the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file by setting `PermitRootLogin yes` to (as I understood) remove the password request, but it still show the same thing ... What should I do?

Comment: did you restart the server? How did you set up authentication? You should be able to see the reason for failure in some of the files in `/var/log/`

Comment: yes I restared it, nothing changed!

Comment: how to setup the authentication?

Answer (score 0):

SSH means Secure Shell. That means that it uses SSL to create a safe tunnel.

Which means, that if there are no passwords, a certificate is needed. So, you'll have to create private and public keys and set them up. I.e. in configuration set correct paths to these files.

To create certificates use OpenSSL.

Or, you can use pexpect module to pass in the password.

pexpect() will start the process, wait for login and/or password and fill them in correctly. It is not hard.

If you want to avoid this, and this is only for private benchmarking, you can use telnet instead of SSH. It is basically the same thing without the SSL. You will have to start the telnet server, and use the telnet client. Both are available on most distros without any installs.

Comment: I see, is there a tutorial I can follow for this?
I prefere understanding this and using it :p

Comment: A little Googling would result for example in this: http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/346/python-how-to-access-ssh-with-pexpect/

Comment: Here is explained how to get passwordless SSH per user session. Not for all users on this box: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: Google est mater studiorum.